# Angular + material sass : style is sometimes wrong

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, jhipster

Something weird appens to my app : most of the time the style is 100% functional and as expected, and sometimes (it seems random) it's not fully loaded. Some height, width, margin and padding are wrong.

What is pretty weird is that I have no error, and I can't find a reason why this is happening. One day I can work few hours and never see this glitch, then the day after, I see it several times.

In any case, hitting F5 to reload the page solve the issue, which makes me think it's more a loading issue, but I'm not sure.

I'm working on an app based en JHipster, with Angular, Material, and sass.

> angular.json

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "inlineStyle": true,
        "inlineTemplate": false,
        "spec": false,
        "prefix": "jhi",
        "styleExt": "scss"
     },
```

I've got a file global.scss which includes some other files :

> global.scss

```
@import './theme.scss';

@import './utils/backgrounds.scss';
@import './utils/borders.scss';
@import './utils/buttons.scss';
@import './utils/cards.scss';
@import './utils/display.scss';
@import './utils/margin.scss';
@import './utils/modal.scss';
@import './utils/padding.scss';
@import './utils/position.scss';
@import './utils/size.scss';
@import './utils/text.scss';
@import './utils/input.scss';
```

As it works fine most of the time, my guess is that there is no error in these files. But I probably do miss something here.

It happens on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, so I don't think the browser is the issue.

Just let me know if you need more code, or anything.

Edit 1 :
I'm actually wondering if it could be that I override few material elements in one page, and override them a different way in another page.

Comment: Did you manage to find out what the issue was? I'm facing a similar issue and it seems some material styles are loaded correctly initially but are not (completely) loaded with a refresh.

Comment: It seems like I overrided lots of material classes, which leaded to this kind of problems. I create new class instead of overriding, and since then, it works better.